# gnuplot thousands of values

Tags: gnuplot, postgresql

i want to plot the contents of a database. It contains pairs of timestamp (e.g. `1298136675887128524`) and power consumption of a node at that time (e.g. `159.562042`). The power consumption is measured every 10th ms. It is a PSQL database. I am not really used to gnuplot so i ask before i spend a lot of time trying it the wrong way...

My idea would be to export the values i want to plot into a plain file like this:

```
1298136675887128524 159.562042  
1298136675888238531 160.124031  
1298136675890241275 158.321967
```

Then i would scale the timestamp so that it is represented on the x-axis in a user-readable way and try to plot everything. Since i am talking about >100000 of these lines i am not quite sure if this is the best way..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is *a* way; 100,000 values is no big deal for gnuplot. Have a look at this: http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datetime-e.html for formatting time data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to "scale" your xaxis. Just:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
plot 'file' u 1:2
```

or something similar.

Use "every *n*" to skip *n-1* points while plotting, if your plot is too dense.